# Getting 'TypeError: interpolate is not a function' in React-Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I am **learning `react-native`** currently.

I'm on this Project that **uses mainly - `react-navgation`,`FlatList`** and **`react-native-magnus`** for UI.
It **takes in
an Array of Objects, and uses FlatList to return a list of Cards(from Magnus UI) for each of the Array Item.**

The Navigaton Structure is like this →
[Link to Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wyg6K.png)

For Better Accessibility, I'm attaching my project along, hope it helps →
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/4b8af09bde680e8e17bcc05a662e4ef820210604152955/6b3f64

**In my Code, I'm stuck at this error** →

```sh
TypeError: interpolate is not a function. (In 'interpolate(this.progress, {
              inputRange: [PROGRESS_EPSILON, 1],
              outputRange: [0, 1]
            })', 'interpolate' is undefined)

This error is located at:
    in NavigationContainer (at App.js:13)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

Stack trace:
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
  node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
  node_modules\expo-error-recovery\build\ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:164:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
  node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
  node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
  [native code]:null in flushedQueue
  [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

###### These are the major JS files of the project ↓, but I've also mentioned a link to the entire project above ↑

**CODE**
*App.js*

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import Navigator from './routes/drawer';

//Test Screens //
// import MagnusCard from './magnus/magnusCard'

export default function App() {
  return (

    <Navigator /> //<<

    //Test Screens //
    // <MagnusCard />

  )
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**CODE**
*drawer.js*

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';

// stacks
import HomeStack from './homeStack';
import AboutStack from './aboutStack';

// drawer navigation options
const RootDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: HomeStack,
    },
    About: {
        screen: AboutStack,
    },
});

export default createAppContainer(RootDrawerNavigator);
```

**CODE**
*homeStack.js*

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

import Home from '../screens/homeStack/home'
import ReviewDetails from '../screens/homeStack/reviewDetails'

//Shared Components
import Header from '../shared/header';

const screens = {
    Home: {
        screen: Home,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
            return {
                headerTitle: () => <Header title="Home" navigation={navigation} />
            }
        }

    },
    ReviewDetails: {
        screen: ReviewDetails,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: "Review Details"
        }
    },
}

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(screens);

export default HomeStack;
```

**CODE**
*home.js*

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, FlatList, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

// Shared Components
import MagnusCard from '../../magnus/magnusCard';

export default function Home({ navigation }) {

    const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([
        { title: 'Zelda, Breath of Fresh Air', rating: 5, body: 'lorem ipsum', key: '1' },
        { title: 'Gotta Catch Them All (again)', rating: 4, body: 'lorem ipsum', key: '2' },
        { title: 'Not So "Final" Fantasy', rating: 3, body: 'lorem ipsum', key: '3' },
    ]);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.topBox}>
                <Button
                    onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('ReviewDetails') }}
                    title="Details" style={styles.btnToRevDetails} />
                <Text style={styles.explainerText}>←Click here to view Review Screen</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.listOfItems}>

                <FlatList data={reviews} renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        {/* onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ReviewDetails', item)} */}

                        <MagnusCard />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                )} />
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
    },
    topBox: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        margin: 4, padding: 10, alignItems: 'center'
    },
    listOfItems: { margin: 10, padding: 4 },
    btnToRevDetails: {
        flex: 3
    },
    explainerText: {
        flex: 7,
        fontSize: 16,
    }
})
```

Comment: looks like there's an animation somewhere that's missing a dependency?

Answer (score 44):

I too faced this issue and broke my head for the last few weeks. This looks to be the version conflict between the `react-navigation-drawer` package with react-native-reanimated. Just now got it fixed. interpolate() was renamed to interpolateNode() in react-native-reanimated@2+. No need to downgrade the react-native-reanimated package.

A simple way to fix this for now is (I tried to submit a pull request on the `react-navigation-drawer` library, however, it is made read-only. So you can change this locally)

1. Open the `Drawer.js` file found in the `<project folder>/node_modules/react-navigation-drawer/lib/module/views/` folder.
2. You will find interpolate in two places, replace the `interpolate` with `interpolateNode` in those two places.

Rebuild your code. It should work.

Comment: worked for me too but  is there another solution  in case i want to test the app on other pc ?

Comment: Once App is built, then there is no need for this change. The App can run in another device. If you are setting up the dev env in other PC, then the same has to be done in all the places

Comment: Since navigation drawer seems abandoned, I recommend using a tool like https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package to persist your fixes across your team.

Comment: Use Patch package after making changes

Comment: this is a temporary solution. If someone clones the repo and does yarn install/npm install they are gonna run into this problem

Answer (score 12):

`interpolate()` was renamed to `interpolateNode()` in Reanimated 2.

Answer (score 7):

I meet this error and fixed it by downgrading `react-native-reanimate` to `2.1.0`. try it but I think there is a bug because after deleting node_modules and installing again the issue was reproduced and solved it by uninstalling the package(`react-native-reanimate`) and installing it again with `2.1.0` version

Answer (score 6):

Maybe your react-navigation-drawer version is conflicting with the version of react-native-reanimated. Try to run `npm i --save react-native-reanimated@1.0.0`.

If possible share your `package.json` code.

Comment: Yes,  react-native-router-flux 4.3.1 with react-native-reanimated 1.31.2 works( `do NOT use react-native-reanimated 2.x` )

Comment: react-native-reanimated `1.31.2` doesn't exist, `1.13.3` is the last version 1.X

Answer (score 3):

Possibly it's a bug which causing this error. You can install (`react-native-reanimated@1.13.1`) and then `expo start --clear`

Answer (score 3):

I also faced this issue and you don't have to downgrade your react-native-reanimated. In the latest versions of reanimated, interpolate was changed to interpolateNode.
So all you have to do is to open the **Drawer.js** file found in:

**node_modules\react-navigation-drawer\lib\module\views** and replace **interpolate** with **interpolateNode**. It is in **two places**, so make sure you change both of them.

This should fix the issue.

Comment: This hack might fix the issue but one should not edit the source code of it's dependencies. This will only work on your computer and will require this change upon each new population of node_modules. This should be fixed in a patch release of react-navigation-drawer itself.

Comment: Why same answer posted?

Answer (score 1):

### Use Animated.interpolateNode

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function MyTabBar({ state, descriptors, navigation, position }) {
  console.log("hi")
  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingTop: 20 }}>
      {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
        const { options } = descriptors[route.key];
        const label =
          options.tabBarLabel !== undefined
            ? options.tabBarLabel
            : options.title !== undefined
            ? options.title
            : route.name;

        const isFocused = state.index === index;

        const onPress = () => {
          const event = navigation.emit({
            type: 'tabPress',
            target: route.key,
          });

          if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
            navigation.navigate(route.name);
          }
        };

        const onLongPress = () => {
          navigation.emit({
            type: 'tabLongPress',
            target: route.key,
          });
        };
        // modify inputRange for custom behavior
        const inputRange = state.routes.map((_, i) => i);
        const opacity = Animated.interpolateNode(position, {
          inputRange,
          outputRange: inputRange.map((i) => (i === index ? 1 : 0)),
        });

        return (
          <TouchableOpacity
            accessibilityRole="button"
            accessibilityState={isFocused ? { selected: true } : {}}
            accessibilityLabel={options.tabBarAccessibilityLabel}
            testID={options.tabBarTestID}
            onPress={onPress}
            onLongPress={onLongPress}
            style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Animated.Text style={{ opacity }}>{label}</Animated.Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Settings!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function ProfileScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Profile!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
     {/* <Stack.Navigator>*/}
      <Stack.Navigator tabBar={(props) => <MyTabBar {...props} />}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

1)Open the Drawer.js file found in /node_modules/react-navigation-drawer/lib/module/views/Drawer.js folder

2. You will find interpolate in two places, replace the interpolate with interpolateNode in those two places.
   Rebuild your code. It should work.