# Unable to resolve module react-native-reanimated/src/core/AnimatedEvent

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-reanimated

This is my first post so my apologies if I leave out some important details that will make it easier to answer the question.
As I was working on my project for my app development class I stumbled upon an error that I cannot fix/figure out what's causing it. I did not mess with any of the node modules and the app was working perfectly fine before the error message.

**Image of error message**

[image]

I have attempted to clear the cache, re install and update some of the packages that I needed for this project, and looked for any errors within the code of my project. No luck after 2 hours of attempts.

Are there any recommendations of that I need to do to fix this? Should I start the project from scratch again?
Thank you all!

Comment: are you runninig this app in android or ios?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cd ios && pod install? Also, upload your package.json file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests react-navigation-drawer is trying to find a component which doesn't exist. Implying your versions are out of sync.

I was able resolve this issue by upgrading react-navigation@4.0.0.

Comment: You may find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67840220/getting-typeerror-interpolate-is-not-a-function-in-react-native